# Can Webclient decode from iso-8859-1 to utf-8?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I faced a problem that the `Jackson2JsonDecoder` class always decodes content to `UTF-8` charset, but I get content in `iso-8859-1` and instead of viewing it correctly, I get unreadable chars.
For example, I recieve **frühestens** in `iso-8859-1` and after Jackson2JsonDecoder I got **frÃ¼hestens**.

I'm using spring boot 2.5.1 version.

I created custom `Jackson2JsonDecoder` to getBytes in correct charset, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way. Maybe I don't understant basic coding stuff.

Jackson2JsonDecoder:

```
...
return decoded.map(s -> DefaultDataBufferFactory.sharedInstance.wrap(s.getBytes(StandartCharset.UTF_8)));
...
```

CustomJackson2JsonDecoder:

```
...
return decoded.map(s -> DefaultDataBufferFactory.sharedInstance.wrap(s.getBytes(charset)));
...
```

Can somebody correct me or explain why default `Jackson2JsonDecoder` always getBytes only in `UTF-8`

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10016086/1575188

Comment: thank you! I saw this question, but in my case Jackson knows the MimeType and even uses it for decoding, but after always tries to get the bytes in UTF-8