# Unable to deserialize a property with umlaut characters in value, error is Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x65

Tags: json, jackson, deserialization

I am using a Custom deserializer to parse the json node to appropriate subclass. When some of properties have umlaut characters , code fails at `parser.readValueAsTree()`. I tried using JsonDeserializer over property as well but it is never been called. I want to strip these accent characters from parser and then deserialize it. Is there a way to modify some of the key value properties to remove these characters and then read the json node?

Below is the code :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.TreeNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.TextNode;


public class CustomAddressDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Address> {

    
    protected CustomAddressDeserializer() {
        super(Address.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Address deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        TreeNode node = parser.readValueAsTree();
        //code fails at this point
    
    }
}
```

json node is a list of addresses which contains city with accent characters

Comment: Can you edit your question and add example `JSON` payload and code which reproduces this bug?

Comment: sure, so I have a list object which contains key as city    e.g; as shown below                              
 "listObject": [
        {
                     
            "city": "Óerlin",
            "country": "CA",
            "postalCode": "90001",
            
            
            
            "territory": "ON"
        }
    ], the city has accent character in it

Comment: Is there a way to validate the json before deserailization from JsonParser and replace these accent characters. All the code examples which I see validates on json string

Comment: I think this is not a problem with `Jackson`. Try to create a simple test where you provide `JSON` payload as a `String`. How do you read receive this `JSON`? Do you read it from file? Try to read it is as `UTF-8`. [Jackson ObjectMapper with UTF-8 encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004241/jackson-objectmapper-with-utf-8-encoding)

Comment: Thank you so much @MichałZiober
  for the suggestion. I figured this out right after posting my question.

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem was actually with the encoding. I have to explicity set the encoding to UTF-8 in my VM args.
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

This solved the problem.