# Default encoding of the output of Objectmapper.writeValueAsString?

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

Can someone tell me what is the default encoding of the serialized string generated by the usage of ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString method ??

I am assuming it should be UTF-8 because this method is used for the purpose of serializing class objects, the output of which is ideally a JSON ??

I have tried checking the [documentation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) but i did not find any specific mention of this UTF-8 around this method.

Comment: Encoding is how you convert from string to bytes. Strings don't inherently have encodings.

Comment: `writeValueAsBytes()` does specify its encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Jackson's encoding is not set on a specific method level, but a whole `ObjectMapper`. By default it uses UTF-8, but in some scenarios UTF-16/32 might be used.

This answer may help you understand the problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/10016086/2879245